# Adding Amazon RDS as slave to external postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, master-slave

We want to migrate an external postgresql database into amazon RDS however for some time we need to keep both of them working and in sync. I have found ways of doing it but only with RDS being the master and not the Slave. Is there a good and viable solution which could help us?

Answer (score -1):

There is AWS service Database Migration Service which can be used to migrate external databases to Amazon AWS RDS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html

It supports postgresql 9.4 and higher.

There are different task types and you need to use Ongoing Replication to keep them sync.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Task.CDC.html

To setup that task you need to enable Logical Replication for source database